# Onclick form submit as button submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a link with onclick attr to submit my form. Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunc()">lorem ipsum</a>

function myFunc() {
$('.ajaxform').submit();
}
```

The problem is.. I'm using an ajax function to do a non-refresh submit.. And I have another script like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

If I use a input button type submit the ajax works.. But it doesnt work using the onclick submit... How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using `ajaxform` and `myForm` which is the correct class

Comment: other than that it is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/um9acxfw/2/

Comment: sorry.. the correct is ajaxform

Comment: did it fix the error

Comment: No.. still stucked =(

Comment: can you edit the jsfiddle to recreate your issue.... if you see the console the submit method is getting called in the case of the fiddle

Comment: Why not simply avoid using onclick? And add the click event handler on the JS, I think its cleaner and easier to read (Just an opinion though).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `<a>` attribute then instead of inline `onclick` attribute write the `click` function seperately and then use `event.preventDefault();` and then submit the form

```
<a id='someId' href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</a> //Give some id
    $(function(){
     $('#someId').click(function(){
     event.preventDefault(); //This will prevent the default action of <a> attribute

     $('.ajaxform').submit(function(){
      //write the functionality here

        });

    }); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
You can add css to a submit button to look like a link and replace it with your link.

**Option 2**
 
**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="#" >
<input type="text" class="youwant" name="youwant" id="youwant" />
<a href="#" class="myform" id="myform">lorem ipsum</a>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').on("click", function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

I didn't try it but it may help you, just give a try and do reply if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 $("#tbutton").click(function(){
     var frmValues = $('#validation').serialize();
     $.ajax({
    type: $this.attr('method'),
    url: "hello.php",
    data: frmValues
})
.done(function () {
    $("#para").text("Serialized! Input String is " + frmValues);
})
.fail(function () {
    $("#para").text("An error occured");
});
event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```